# Assign queried Decimal to a Decimal variable

Tags: apex, convert, aggregateresult

question - want to use a number field called Rebate_Amount__c on object called Rebate_schedule__c (child to Opportunity) to cut a rebate on the Amount__c field on a Revenue_schedule_Summary_Amount__c object. 
The issue is frustratingly basic - turn that result into a decimal. Please assist.

```
 trigger ApplyRSSAHaircut on Revenue_Schedule_Summary_Amount__c (after insert) {

        List <Revenue_Schedule_Summary_Amount__c> RSSAsToCut = new List <Revenue_Schedule_Summary_Amount__c>();
        List <Rebate_Schedule__c> ApplicableRebates = new List <Rebate_Schedule__c>();
        Decimal RebateFactor;

        For(Revenue_Schedule_Summary_Amount__c RSSA:Trigger.new){

            List<AggregateResult> results = [select MAX (Rebate_factor__c)   from Rebate_schedule__c where 
  Opportunity__c =: RSSA.Revenue_Schedule_Summary__r.Opportunity__c
                                    AND Rebate_Start_Date__c <=: RSSA.Date__c
                                    AND Rebate_End_Date__c >=: RSSA.Date__c
                           ];

            RebateFactor = (turn the MAX into a usable decimal how?);

            RSSA.Amount__c = (RSSA.Amount__c * (RebateFactor ));
            RSSAsToCut.add(RSSA);


        }
        update RSSAsToCut;

    }
```

Comment: There are a few issues with this Trigger you need to solve before you move onto getting that decimal value, what are you trying to do?  The SOQL inside your For loop is no bueno

Comment: Every RevSchedSumAmmount needs to check if there is a rebate_schedule__c on the Opportunity, then apply the Rebate_factor__c to the Amount on the RSSA. So I am looking for rebate factor applicable. I already see I need a null check somewhere I think...

Comment: The problem Eric is pointing at is that you can get up to 200 records in each `trigger.new` batch. And you're doing one query for each... which will blow up since the Gov Limit is 100 queries per context.

Comment: Realizing an issue - can't do this with an after insert b/c it's updating the same record. I am thinking I need to push to a future. Will resume work next week.... if this question expands should I edit the original more or mark an answer and start a new one if needed?

Comment: I am moving the processing to an @future class called out and will address the SOQL in Loop issues. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with the commenter above that said that you have some SoQL-In-Loop problems (and you DO want to get them fixed ASAP) but, in the meantime, you can get the value like this

```
RebateFactor = (Decimal) results[0].get(0);
```

or, add this to the query

```
[select MAX (Rebate_factor__c)  MaxRebate from....
```

and then

```
RebateFactor = (Decimal) results[0].get('MaxRebate');
```

Comment: Thank you, I missed how the result was getting named after and therefore could be retrived.

Comment: If this solved your problem, please mark it as accepted so others can benefit.

Comment: This solved my titular question but am still reviewing - protocol?

Comment: No need to accept anything until you've decided that the answer you got is the correct one. :) And that answer does not have to be mine.

Comment: Sebastian - don't you mean to use `results[0].get('expr0')` in the first example?